# Hydro from Mac OS X Homebrew: sudo pip install -U empy fails

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Hi Everyone!
I am trying to install the Hydro in Mac OS X Lion 10.8.4 (about to update it to 10.8.5). I am stuck at the following command:
ros_catkin_ws jasprit$ rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro hydro -y
The error I get is in the terminal console text below:**

Jasprits-MacBook-Pro:ros_catkin_ws jasprit$ rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro hydro -y
executing command [sudo pip install -U empy]
Password:
Downloading/unpacking empy
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement empy (from versions: latest, latest)
Cleaning up...
No distributions matching the version for empy
Storing complete log in /Users/jasprit/Library/Logs/pip.log
ERROR: the following rosdeps failed to install
pip: command [sudo pip install -U empy] failed**

**I went to the Logs directory and checked the "pip.log" to understand what went wrong and here is what I get:**

---

/usr/local/bin/pip run on Thu Sep 26 14:12:05 2013
Downloading/unpacking empy
Getting page https: //pypi.python.org/simple/empy/
URLs to search for versions for empy:
https: //pypi.python.org/simple/empy/
Getting page http: //www.alcyone.com/software/empy/
Skipping page http: //www.alcyone.com/software/empy/empy-latest.tar.gz (from https:  //pypi.python.org/simple/EmPy/) because of Content-Type: application/x-gzip
Analyzing links from page https: //pypi.python.org/simple/EmPy/
Skipping link http: //www.alcyone.com/software/empy/ (from https ://pypi.python.org/simple/EmPy/); not a file
Found link http: //www.alcyone.com/software/empy/empy-latest.tar.gz (from https: //pypi.python.org/simple/EmPy/), version: latest
Analyzing links from page http: //www.alcyone.com/software/empy/
Skipping link http: //www.alcyone.com/software/empy/index.html (from http: //www.alcyone.com/software/empy/); unknown archive format: .html
Skipping link http: //www.alcyone.com/software/empy/#index (from http: //www.alcyone.com/software/empy/); not a file
Skipping link http: //www.alcyone.com/software/empy/#refindex (from http: //www.alcyone.com/software/empy/); not a file
Found link http: //www.alcyone.com/software/empy/empy-latest.tar.gz (from http: //www.alcyone.com/software/empy/), version: latest
Skipping link http: //www.gnu.org/copyleft/lesser.html (from http ://www.alcyone.com/software/empy/); unknown archive format: .html
Skipping link mailto: empy-announce-list-subscribe@alcyone.com (from http:  //www.alcyone.com/software/empy/); unknown archive format: .com
Skipping link empy-list-subscribe@alcyone.com (from http: //www.alcyone.com/software/empy/); unknown archive format: .com
Skipping link http: //www.alcyone.com/software/empy/#refname (from http: //www.alcyone.com/software/empy/); not a file
Skipping link http: //www.alcyone.com/software/empy/#refsub (from http: //www.alcyone.com/software/empy/); not a file
Skipping link http: //www.alcyone.com/software/empy/#refi (from http: //www.alcyone.com/software/empy/); not a file
Skipping link http: //www.alcyone.com/software/empy/#refcontinue (from http: //www.alcyone.com/software/empy/); not a file
Skipping link http: //www.alcyone.com/software/empy/#refbreak (from http: //www.alcyone.com/software/empy/); not a file
Skipping link http: //www.alcyone.com/max/info/m4.html (from http: //www.alcyone.com/software/empy/); unknown archive format: .html
Skipping link http: //www.seindal.dk/rene/gnu/ (from http: //www.alcyone.com/software/empy/); not a file
Skipping link http: //www.alcyone.com/software/empy/#reftry (from http: //www.alcyone.com/software/empy/); not a file
Skipping link http: //www.alcyone.com/software/empy/#reffor (from http: //www.alcyone.com/software/empy/); not a file
Skipping link http: //www.alcyone.com/software/empy/#ref0 (from http: //www.alcyone.com/software/empy/); not a file
Skipping link http: //www.alcyone.com/software/empy/#defunct (from http: //www.alcyone.com/software/empy/); not a file
Skipping link http: //www.alcyone.com/software/empy/#refdefunct (from http ://www.alcyone.com/software/empy/); not a file
Skipping link http: //www.alcyone.com/software/empy/#ref... (from http: //www.alcyone.com/software/empy/); not a file
Skipping link http: //www.alcyone.com/software/empy/#deprecated (from http: //www.alcyone.com/software/empy/); not a file
Skipping link http: //www.alcyone.com/software/empy/#refdeprecated (from http: //www.alcyone.com/software/empy/); not a file
Skipping link http: //www.alcyone.com/max/ (from http: //www.alcyone.com/software/empy/); not a file
Skipping link software@alcyone.com (from http: //www.alcyone.com/software/empy/); unknown archive format: .com
Skipping link http: //www.alcyone.com/software/empy/home/max/projects/empy/doc/em.html (from http: //www.alcyone.com/software/empy/); unknown archive format: .html
Skipping link http: //www.alcyone.com/software/empy/home/max/projects/empy/doc/emlib.html (from http: //www.alcyone.com/software/empy/); unknown archive format: .html
Skipping link http: //happydoc.sourceforge.net (from http: //www.alcyone.com/software/empy/); not a file
Ignoring link http: / /www.alcyone.com/software/empy/empy-latest.tar.gz (from https: //pypi.python.org/simple/EmPy/), version latest is a pre-release (use --pre to allow).
Ignoring link http: //www.alcyone.com/software/empy/empy-latest.tar.gz (from http: //www.alcyone.com/software/empy/), version latest is a pre-release (use --pre to allow).
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement empy (from versions: latest, latest)
Cleaning up...
Removing temporary dir /private/tmp/pip_build_root...
No distributions matching the version for empy
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.4.1-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 134, in main
status = self.run(options, args)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.4.1-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 236, in run
requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.4.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 1085, in prepare_files
url = finder.find_requirement(req_to_install, upgrade=self.upgrade)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.4.1-py2.7.egg/pip/index.py", line 309, in find_requirement
raise DistributionNotFound('No distributions matching the version for %s' % req)
DistributionNotFound: No distributions matching the version for empy

**It looks like the script is trying to fetch a file for installing Embedded Python and is not able to find a match. Has anyone come across this? Does anyone know a work around for this?
(I am a newbie and hence if my question doesnt provide enough information, please feel free to ask.)**

Thanks in advance,

Jasprit

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/83801/hydro-from-mac-os-x-homebrew:-sudo-pip-install--u-empy-fails/) by [jaspritsgill](https://answers.ros.org/users/7141/jaspritsgill/) on ROS Answers with karma: 88 on 2013-09-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found a work around for this. I used "sudo easy_install empy" and Embedded Python was installed successfully. I was able to proceed with "rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro hydro -y" after that.

---

Originally posted by [jaspritsgill](https://answers.ros.org/users/7141/jaspritsgill/) with karma: 88 on 2013-10-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dmp](https://answers.ros.org/users/7481/dmp/) on 2013-10-05**:
This should probably go in the installation page ... I got the same exact issue, thank you!

**Comment by [jensenb](https://answers.ros.org/users/4449/jensenb/) on 2013-11-12**:
Thanks, that did the trick for me too. Any idea why pip fails?

**Comment by [jaspritsgill](https://answers.ros.org/users/7141/jaspritsgill/) on 2013-11-12**:
From what I understand, pip tries to fetch the Embedded Python (EmPy) from the page: https: //pypi.python.org/simple/empy/. It finds file empy-latest.tar.gz but doesnt find a match. Probably a poor code for version check, in one of the script files, that fails after new version of empy was launched.

**Comment by [jensenb](https://answers.ros.org/users/4449/jensenb/) on 2013-11-20**:
I should correct my previous statement. The easy_install command completed successfully, but it built and installed an egg package, which apparently is supported by catkin.

**Comment by [jensenb](https://answers.ros.org/users/4449/jensenb/) on 2013-11-20**:
Description here: http://answers.ros.org/question/100741/catkin-fails-on-osx-109-cant-find-__main__-module-in-empy-31-py27eggempyc/?answer=101061#post-id-101061